# Как разделить эту процедуру на функции и процедуры pascal

Tags: строки, pascal, pascalabc.net

Задание выглядит следующим образом : сделать все буквы большими в тех словах, которые начинаются и заканчиваются с одной и той же буквы.

Обязательно нужно использовать процедуры и функции.

Вот процедура

```pascal
procedure print_stirng();
var
  s, word, sign: string;
  punc: set of char;
  i: integer;

begin
  Readln(s);
  punc := ['.', ',', ' ', '-', ';', ':', '?'];//добавьте нужные знаки пунктуации
  i := 1;
  while (i <= length(s)) do
  begin
    while (i <= length(s)) and (not (s[i] in punc)) do
    begin
      word := word + s[i];
      i := i + 1;
    end;
    if (word[1] = word[length(word)]) then 
    begin
      for var j := 1 to length(word) do
        write(UpCase(word[j]));
      write(' ')
    end 
    else write(word + ' ');
    Word := '';
    i := i + 1;
  end;
end;
```

И она прекрасно работает, просто не могу понять, как можно её разделить. Не обязательно использовать эту процедуру, если напишите заново - буду благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум можно сделать одну функцию, которая в качестве параметра принимает слово, и выдаёт True/False в зависимости от того, равны ли буквы в конце и начале слова. Т.е. перенести в функцию условие

```
if (word[1] = word[length(word)]) then
```